# Conditional apache rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some URL paths in the form of:

```
/cat/_CNAME_(/_SUB_(/_SUB_))(/_ATR_/_ATRVAL_(/_ATR_/ATRVAL_))(/page/_PNUM_)
```

That are needed to be converted to:

```
/cat/_CNAME_(/_SUB_(/_SUB_))(/page/_PNUM_)?(_ATR_=_ATRVAL_(&_ATR_=_ATRVAL_))
```

Some clarifications:

- *CNAME*, *SUB*, *ATR*, *ATRVAL* & *PNUM* are dynamic
- *SUB*, *ATR* => *ATRVAL*, page => *PNUM* are optional leaving *CNAME* as the only obligatory term in the URL path
- *SUB* and *ATR* => *ATRVAL* can be present multiple times
- The only way to separate *SUB* from *ATR* => *ATRVAL* is that *ATR* name will always begin with either 'attr_' or 'prod_' while no other term will have that prefix

Meaning that the following paths should be converted:

this

```
/cat/magazines/lifestyle/attr_shape/portrait/prod_cat/lifestyle/
```

to

```
/cat/magazines/lifestyle/?attr_shape=portrait&prod_cat=lifestyle
```

this

```
/cat/magazines/attr_shape/landscape/page/5/
```

to

```
/cat/magazines/page/5?attr_shape=landscape
```

this

```
/cat/magazines/lifestyle/attr_shape/square/attr_size/20x20/page/2
```

to

```
/cat/magazines/lifestyle/page/2?attr_shape=square&attr_size=20x20
```

Comment: ok, thanks for letting us know what you are up to :-).  Seriously, we expect you to start working on it, do research, debug, ...  Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Nic3500 no problem at all (for letting you know what I'm up to) :) Seriously, I know that I am asking for too much, *BUT* it's so complicated [at least for my level of expertise] that couldn't find anything similar, *SO* in the midtime I do my research, experimenting and *WHEN* I find the solution or *someone else comes up with one*, I'll try to restructure my question (to be more searchable) in order more people to be helped from it. I am a good person, I swear!